# Converting COMP-3 columns in Mainframes to readable format using Record Editor tool

Tags: editor, record, data-conversion, readable, comp-3

[image]

This is the file which we received as Binary from Mainframes which includes COMP-3  columns as well along with other columns

And when we tried loading this Binary file into Record Editor, It is displaying Special Characters

Kindly let us know step by step process from Starting to Ending on How to process COMP-3 columns and load into Record Editor.

Comment: I started braking the question down so far I have 2 questions / answers: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45794642/how-do-you-edit-a-binary-mainframe-file-in-the-recordeditor-using-a-cobol-copybo and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45812354/edit-a-mainframe-file-in-the-recordeditor-without-a-copybook/45812481

Answer (score 0):

So what have you **tried** ???, In the last question I suggested:

You will have to update RecordEditor/JRecord

- The font will need to be ebcdic (cp037 for US ebcdic; for other lookup)
- The *File Structure/File Organisation* needs to change (Fixed length / VB)

Have you tried this ??? (Menu Option **Record Layout >> Edit Layout** see picture in the next section) Then select your
layout in the column on the left of the Screen. Finally select the Extra tab. There are help screens (F01).

Layout Edit Screen (Extra Tab):
[image]

The reason for the funny characters is because you are trying to view
an ebcdic file with ascii.

---

[image]

In general to view a mainframe file

- If you have Cobol Copybook, load the cobol Copybook (Menu Option **Record Layout >> Load Cobol Copybook**).
  It helps if you specify a sample file, The RecordEditor will check encoding file organisation etc. This [Question and Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45794642/how-do-you-edit-a-binary-mainframe-file-in-the-recordeditor-using-a-cobol-copybo) deals with loading a Cobol copybook
- If you do not have a Cobol Copybook, You can use the **File Wizard** (Menu Option **Record Layout >> Layout Wizard**).
  The wizard has a series of screens

  - Get the file name and type of file:
  - Select the Encoding and File structure
  - Find the fields, The system will search for fields but you can select a
    field by clicking on a column. To delete a field, Click on the starting column.
  - Finally you name (and type) fields