# Edit a Mainframe file in the RecordEditor without a copybook

Tags: record, binaryfiles, mainframe, copybook

How do you **Edit** a (binary EBCDIC) **Mainframe** file in the [RecordEditor](https://sourceforge.net/projects/record-editor/) **with out** a Cobol Copybook.

How do you generate Java code to read the file using the [RecordEditor](https://sourceforge.net/projects/record-editor/).

**Note:** This is an attempt to split a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45729690/converting-comp-3-columns-in-mainframes-to-readable-format-using-record-editor-t/45780399) that is far to broad to give meaningful answer to
into a series of simpler Question and Answer's.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try and **avoid** editing a binary file with a Cobol Copybook if at all possible. This should only be attempted as a **last resort** !!!.

Try and get
that **Cobol copybook** (or some field layout document) for the file !!!

---

Some general advise:

- It is feasible when dealing with 10 / 20 fields in a record but not if there a thousands of fields in a Record.
- Take your time do not rush the process. Try and get each step correct before moving on
- Finally upgrade to the latest version of the **RecordEditor** (currently 0.98.4)
- This process will also work for normal Text file as well

### RecordEditor Layout Wizard

To start the wizard select option **Record Layouts >>> Layout Wizard**.

[image]

#### File Structure screen

The file structure screen has 3 purposes:

- Get the File structure - It could be Fixed Width, VB, Windows/Unix Text file
- Get the Record-Length (if it is a fixed width file).
- Get the font (character-set / encoding)

The **RecordEditor** will try and work this out for you

[image]

#### Field Selection Screen

The **RecordEditor** will try and work out where fields start and end but
it  is not perfect. You need to **carefully check**  and **correct** its choices

[image]

On this screen, the fields are displayed in *alternating colors*

- you create/delete a field by clicking on
- use the **Clear Fields** button clear all the fields
- you can change what field-types to search for using the various check box's (e.g. *Mainframe Zones Decimal*)
- The **Add Fields** will do another field search

#### Field Definition screen

On this screen you define the field names and Types. You may need to go back to the **Field Selection Screen* to adjust the fields

[image]

#### Editing the file

Once the `Record Layout` has been defined, it can be used on the open file screen

[image]

#### Generating Java code

When editing your file, you can generate **java~JRecord** code to read the file
by selecting **Generate >>> Java >>> ...**.

[image]

You can the enter a package-id + generate options:

[image]

and finally your sample java code is generated to read / write the
file.

[image]