# Is there a Windows alternative to Mainframe FileAID?

Tags: amazon-web-services, text-editor, mainframe

For work, I'm on a team that is migrating a system from Mainframe to AWS.  Part of the work I do is using FileAID to work on fixed-width files with custom layouts ([here](https://www.cms.gov/Medicare/Prescription-Drug-Coverage/DrugCoverageClaimsData/Downloads/FileFormat_020806.pdf), if anyone is curious)  What I'm wondering is, is there any sort of a desktop application that has similar file layout display features similar to FileAID?

Answer (score 2):

Two Optioms

- Microfocus Cobol has an editor
- [RecordEditor](https://sourceforge.net/projects/record-editor/) can display fixed width file.

### RecordEditor

The [RecordEditor](https://sourceforge.net/projects/record-editor/) can display Binary Mainframe or PC / Linux text files.

For File Description the RecordEditor can:

- Use File Descriptions entered into it
- Imported Cobol Copybooks
- Cobol Copybooks directly (Single Record File types)
- Xml File Descriptions

Entering filename and Cobol Copybook:

[image: Entering Cobol Copybook]

File Display:

[image]

Record Display:

[image]

**Note:** When first starting the RecordEditor make sure you select the schema and also the Cobol option

### Related question

- [Binary Mainframe Cobol Files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45794642/how-do-you-edit-a-binary-mainframe-file-in-the-recordeditor-using-a-cobol-copybo)
- [RecordEditor Layout Wizard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45812354/edit-a-mainframe-file-in-the-recordeditor-without-a-copybook)

Answer (score 0):

[CudaText](http://www.uvviewsoft.com/cudatext/) editor (free, cross platform) has rich lexer engine, so it's easy to write a "lexer" which supports such formats.

For example, "Intel HEX" is a file format with fixed columns, and lexer "Intel HEX" is present in CudaText addons. It looks like this:

[image: CudaText with Intel HEX]

This lexer even highlights "wrong lines" with red.